# How to add subitems to ExpansionPanelList - ListView.Builder?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  Item({
    this.expandedValue,
    this.headerValue,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });

  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
  List<Item> _subItems;

  List<Item> get getSubItems => _subItems;
  set subItems(List<Item> subItems) {
    _subItems = subItems;
  }
}

List<Item> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
  return List.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return Item(
      headerValue: 'Panel $index',
      expandedValue: 'This is item number $index',
    );
  });
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  List<Item> _data = generateItems(8);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _data.forEach((element) {
      element.subItems = generateItems(3);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: _buildPanel(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList(
      expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
        setState(() {
          _data[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
        });
      },
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(item.headerValue),
            );
          },
          body: Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: item._subItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                return Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Text(
                      position.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, `ExpansionTile` is what you need

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  Item({
    this.headerValue,
    this.expandedValue,
  });

  String headerValue;
  String expandedValue;
  List<Item> subItems;
}

List<Item> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
  return List.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return Item(
      headerValue: 'Panel $index',
      expandedValue: 'This is item number $index',
    );
  });
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  List<Item> _data = generateItems(8);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _data.forEach((element) {
      element.subItems = generateItems(3);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      itemCount: _data.length,
      separatorBuilder: (context, index){
        return const Divider(height: 1.0);
      },
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        final item = _data[index];
        return ExpansionTile(
          title: Text(item.headerValue),
          subtitle: Text(item.expandedValue),
          children: item.subItems.map((subItem){
            return Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text(
                  subItem.expandedValue,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```